# Slice a long video with ffmpeg to little pieces in node js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have a very big video like 3 hours, and I want to slice it to little pieces of 20 minutes each.
This is my initial code :

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    '-i', './videos/long-video.mp4',
    '-codec:v', 'copy', 
    '-codec:a', 'copy', 
    '-f','mp4',
    '-map', '0', '-f', 'segment', '-segment_time', '1200', './videos/pieces/video_%04d.mp4'
  ]);
```

What this code do is slice the video in pieces and save them to the location I provided, so you need to wait until the ffmpeg finish slicing the whole video.
But what I'm looking for is a way to trigger a code when ever ffmpeg has made a new piece so I can insert the video name in database, something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    '-i', './videos/long-video.mp4',
    '-codec:v', 'copy', 
    '-codec:a', 'copy', 
    '-f','mp4',
    '-map', '0', '-f', 'segment', '-segment_time', '1200', 
    'pipe:1'
  ]);
ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // store the video name in database
    console.log('new peice has been made' );
  });
ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('error' );
  });
```

***ffmpeg.stdout.on*** doesn't exit I just made it to indicate what I'm looking for. What does exist is ***ffmpeg.stdout.pipe();*** but again I don't know how to trigger a code whenever a new piece has been made.

Comment: As far as I remember ffmpeg outputs the logs to stderr not stdout so you can add a listener to that, You can whether parse the output of the buffer with RegExp or maybe use `fs.watch` and whenever a new file is created, you can assume that the previous chunk was encoded successfully.

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed i didn't understand what you mean by using `fs.watch` , can you show me please how i can do that

Comment: please check https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener , here is an example -- `var prevChunk; fs.watch('/path/to/videos', (type, filename) => { if(type === 'rename') { /* here a new file was created but still being processed */ if(prevChunk) {updateChunk(prevChunk);} prevChunk = filename; }  });`

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed thanks a lot, it worked , instead of `fs.watch` i use       [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), because `fs.watch` is firing sometimes twice with one file, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but another possibility could be **fluent-ffmpeg** for nodejs:
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Here you can write ffmpeg commands in an fluent way and also react to events:

```
ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi')
  .videoCodec('libx264')
  .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
  .size('320x240')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Processing finished !');
  })
  .save('/path/to/output.mp4');
```